# converting dataframe into matrix and adding ids

Tags: r

I have a dataframe df1, example given below

```
ID  SNP1    SNP2    SNP3    SNP4    SNP5
ID1   1       2      2       0       0
ID2   0       1      0       1       0
ID3   1       2      2       1       1
ID4   0       1      1       0       0
ID5   2       0      2       1       2
```

I would like to convert it into matrix example give below and also to add ids and snps, so I can match it with my another co-variate file for further analysis

```
      ID1  ID2 ID3 ID4 ID5
SNP1    1   0   1   0   2
SNP2    2   1   2   1   0
SNP3    2   0   2   1   2
SNP4    0   1   1   0   1
SNP5    0   0   1   0   2
```

Comment: Don't you just need `t(df)` ?

Comment: `structure(t(df[-1]), dimnames=list(names(df[-1]), df[[1]]))`

Answer (score 2):

Move the `ID` column to rownames, then remove it, convert the data frame to a matrix, and transpose:

```r
df1 <- data.frame(ID = c("ID1", "ID2", "ID3", "ID4", "ID5"), 
                  SNP1 = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 2L), 
                  SNP2 = c(2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 0L), 
                  SNP3 = c(2L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 2L), 
                  SNP4 = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L), 
                  SNP5 = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 2L),
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

rownames(df1) <- df1$ID
df1$ID <- NULL
mat1 <- t(as.matrix(df1))

mat1
#>      ID1 ID2 ID3 ID4 ID5
#> SNP1   1   0   1   0   2
#> SNP2   2   1   2   1   0
#> SNP3   2   0   2   1   2
#> SNP4   0   1   1   0   1
#> SNP5   0   0   1   0   2
```

or with `tibble::column_to_rownames`,

```r
library(tidyverse)

df1 <- data_frame(ID = c("ID1", "ID2", "ID3", "ID4", "ID5"), 
                  SNP1 = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 2L), 
                  SNP2 = c(2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 0L), 
                  SNP3 = c(2L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 2L), 
                  SNP4 = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L), 
                  SNP5 = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 2L))

mat1 <- df1 %>% column_to_rownames('ID') %>% as.matrix() %>% t()

mat1
#>      ID1 ID2 ID3 ID4 ID5
#> SNP1   1   0   1   0   2
#> SNP2   2   1   2   1   0
#> SNP3   2   0   2   1   2
#> SNP4   0   1   1   0   1
#> SNP5   0   0   1   0   2
```

`t()` will coerce to a matrix anyway, but being explicit in coercions is a good habit.

Answer (score 2):

Functions like `rownames` and `colnames` also have a `rownames<-` and `colnames<-` variant which can be used like this:

```
`colnames<-`(data, the_column_names)
```

Thus, you can do this fairly directly by:

- Dropping the first row of `t()`
- Adding in the new column names

Example (using @alistaire's sample data):

```
`colnames<-`(t(df1[-1]), df1[[1]])
##      ID1 ID2 ID3 ID4 ID5
## SNP1   1   0   1   0   2
## SNP2   2   1   2   1   0
## SNP3   2   0   2   1   2
## SNP4   0   1   1   0   1
## SNP5   0   0   1   0   2
```

Note that you need backticks (`` ` ``) or quotes (either `"` or `'`) for these functions to work.

Also, this obviously doesn't change your data, so you need to assign it to  a new object:

```
mat1 <- `colnames<-`(data, the_column_names)
```

---

A few other notes:

- We drop the first column because it's a character vector that needs to become your column names. If you kept it, it would convert the entire matrix to a character matrix.
- We use `[[1]]` to just get the values of the first column. If you just used `df[1]`, you'd be returning a `list`, which can't be assigned as a column name.
- Related to the above, it might be easier to think about it by consistently using `[row, col]` indexing (eg: `'colnames<-'(t(df1[, -1]), df1[, 1])`. However, some "re-implementations" of `data.frame`-like structures (eg: `tbl`s) don't drop dimensions on single-column extraction. Thus, if you're working with a `tbl` and not a `data.frame`, you would need to use the `[[1]]` approach.